# Extracting information with simple Regex expression

Tags: regex

I have this string: OK (0 msec) and need to extract the following using Regex:

- OK
- 0
- msec

All parts may vary, but it will always be TEXT (DECIMAL TEXT)

And, it HAS to be done with Regex

Comment: Out of interest, why does it have to be done with a regex?

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `([a-zA-Z]+)\s\((\d+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)\)`

`OK` in group1

`0` in group 2

`msec` in group 3

Comment: This is what I have been trying, and I expected it to work, but it seems there might be a bug in the Intermapper regex interpeter or something like that.

Comment: try split regex into three regex for localization interpretator issue